# Is this the correct wiring for Honeywell humidifier?

Tags: wiring, humidifier

Additional Info:

Make/Model of furnace: Bryant / 310AAV042090

Link to Installation Instructions: https://www.carrierenterprise.com/bryant-legacy-80-afue-90-000-btuh-multipoise-gas-furnace-310aav042090#tab-documents

I've reconnected my whole house humidifier but wanted to run by what I did with an expert or someone who's done this before.  Don't want to ruin my furnace.

I recently purchased a house with a whole house humidifier, a Honeywell HE360A.
[image: Honeywell HE360A]

The inspector said it wasn't working and sure enough, it doesn't work.  I started troubleshooting the setup and everything looks good until the wiring from the humidifier enters the furnace and ends at some kind of relay.  There's no wiring from the furnace to the relay so there's no power or communication from the furnace to the humidifier.

[image: Relay where wires from humidifier terminate]

I started looking around the circuit board to see if there were any wires or plugs dangling that needed to be plugged in.  That's when I noticed this piece of wiring laying on the floor next to the furnace.  It seems to be the connection between the relay and the furnace circuit board.

[image: Connection wire]

So, I did some research and looked at some wiring diagrams and it looks like I need to do the following:  The end of the wire with the two connectors connects to the relay, doesn't seem to matter what order but I matched the red and the white on the top.  Then the end with one connector and one bare wire goes to the circuit board.  The connector goes to the HUM and the bare wire goes to the COM 24V.  Is this the correct way to wire this?
[image: HUM connection]

[image: COM 24V connection]

Here's the wiring diagram of the furnace.
[image: Furnace Wiring Diagram]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: Added wiring diagram to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my answer.  I've been searching for documentation for the humidifier on how to connect it to the furnace.  This morning, I decided to look for documentation for the furnace to see if it mentioned anything about attaching humidifiers.  I looked up the model number and found the installation instructions online.  In the furnace installation instructions it states:

> 2. Humidifier (HUM)
>    Connect an accessory 24 VAC, 0.5 amp. maximum humidifier (if used) to the 1/4--in male quick--connect HUM terminal and COM--24V screw terminal on the control board thermostat strip. The HUM terminal is energized
>    when gas valve relay (GVR) is energized. (See Fig. 24.)"

So, there it is. Just had to look for the correct documentation.

Additional Info:

Make/Model of furnace: Bryant / 310AAV042090

Link to Installation Instructions: https://www.carrierenterprise.com/bryant-legacy-80-afue-90-000-btuh-multipoise-gas-furnace-310aav042090#tab-documents

Comment: Including a link to the docs will help others in the future. Also, be sure to come back and give yourself a check-mark so others know this has a resolution. Oh, and including the make/model of the furnace in the question (and probably in the answer) would be super useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

If forced to guess the red bare end goes to R and the white plug to 'HUM' and the other two plugs to the bottom terminals of the relay.